# How to hide title of MainAppForm?

Tags: c#

For tracking Windows purpose, I gave a title to my `MainAppForm`:

```
var form = new MainAppForm();
form.Text = "my application";
```

However, I don't want to show this text on my front-end. Is there any way to hide the title?

Comment: you mean you don't want to show form Text in Winforms?

Comment: do you mean you want show an empty title, or you want to hide title area?

Comment: Why would you give a title if you don't want to show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
form.Name = "MyApplication";
```

Do not assign it text if you don't want it to appear in the title bar.

Comment: I guess this is what he actually wanted to do.

Comment: Found a solution: form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

Comment: I have to use text of each window in EnumWindow delegates. That's why I set form.Text instead of form.Name. But thanks anyway, I accepted this answer.